# What is the location of the Qiskit config file?

Tags: qiskit, programming

I'm trying to follow the instructions here https://qiskit.org/documentation/getting_started.html. It says

> The default backend for qiskit.visualization.circuit_drawer() or
>   QuantumCircuit.draw() is the text backend. However, depending on your
>   local environment you may want to change these defaults to something
>   better suited for your use case. This is done with the user config
>   file. By default the user config file should be located in
>   ~/.qiskit/settings.conf and is a .ini file.

I don't see this config file anywhere. Can anyone tell me how I can find the location of this file in order to make the change from the text based plotter to the nicer plotter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are working in Windows, the default location should be `C:\Users\[user]\.qiskit`, which might be hidden by default. Create a text file in that folder named `settings.conf` and set it up how you like.

For example by default

```
from qiskit import *
qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
qc.h(0)
qc.x(1)
qc.draw()
```

produces

[image: text drawer circuit output]

With `settings.conf` in the folder referenced above, containing the two lines

```
[default]
circuit_drawer=mpl
```

the same code produces

[image: mpl drawer circuit output]

Comment: Thank you very much. And since I will be using this on a Mac as well, can I ask where this file should be in a Mac?

Comment: @user1936752  Sorry, I've never worked with qiskit in iOS.  However, if you have your [API token](https://qiskit.org/documentation/install.html#access-ibm-q-systems) stored locally, you should have a file named ``qiskitrc`` in this folder already.  Try doing a search for that file.

Comment: @user1936752 Is it not just ``Users/[user]/.qiskit``?  If not a search for ``.qiskit`` should lead you there as well.

Comment: Thank you - you were indeed correct. However it may be worth adding to your answer that this folder might be hidden! It was for me, hence the trouble finding it

Comment: @user1936752 No problem!  It's in there, first sentence.

Answer (score 4):

Use the command `ls -alt` in Terminal on macOS to find hidden files. It's there. This should work for all Mac users.

Answer (score 1):

I am still unable to see the ~/.qiskit/settings.conf file. Did the listing to show hidden files as well as created a new conda environment for a new qiskit environment.

I am on a mac and following the instructions listed here: https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-prerequisites/setting-the-environment.html

Comment: Hi and welcome to Quantum Computing SE. When you have enough reputation, please add posts like yours as Comment.

Comment: Did you first navigate to the directory using the command:   cd ~/.qiskit/    and then use the command    ls -alt     ?    Also, how did you install python Conda?  I recently ran into an issue of not having PIP installed, which is why I ask how you installed. Make sure pip is installed using: "pip --version". If it's not installed you can do so using "sudo easy_install pip"  PIP is just a helpful tool to download python packages.  See link: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_pip.asp  ... You can use terminal command to search for files..., but there are several files to be search...