# How to set matplolib as default circuit drawer?

Tags: programming, qiskit

I've already tried the instructions on the qiskit page and even from this other question [What is the location of the Qiskit config file?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/8702/what-is-the-location-of-the-qiskit-config-file)
but it doesn´t work, the circuit keeps looking as text based, even i restarted jupyter notebook, and nothing. The settings.conf file wasn't in the directory so i created one but still no results.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a question about a specific python package/functionality and has nothing to do with QC or quantum mechanics per se

Comment: Does it have to be about quantum mechanics? The questiin is about qiskit and is more likely to be answered here than elsewhere.

Comment: This is not a difficult problem, I think. Try `circ.draw('mpl')` and then `plt.show()'. But you really need to describe the situation specifically because it is not clear what really happens.

Comment: the problem is that i want qiskit to plot on mpl by default the circuits and so, but following the instructions of it makes no changes, like if qiskit wasn't able to recognize the settings file or something like that

Answer (score 2):

To check that the content of the `setting.conf` file is properly set you can run the following

```
from qiskit import user_config
user_config.get_config()
```

```
{'circuit_drawer': 'mpl'}
```

If this is not your output, then your `setting.conf` is out of format or in the wrong location. You can fix the location by setting the env variable `QISKIT_SETTINGS`. It is possible to do that in a Jupyter notebook with this magic:

```
%env QISKIT_SETTINGS <path to your setting.conf>
```

Comment: still no changes, first recalling the qisikit user_config but the output gives nothing, then i tried the env variable and again recalling the user_config but gives again nothing

Comment: are you on windows?

Comment: yeah, ive also tried to put it on .ini format but nothing

Comment: what is output of `user_config.DEFAULT_FILENAME`? Could try editing that if it isn't what you expected

Comment: the command is not recognized on the conda prompt

Comment: it's not a command. You can do `from qiskit.user_config import DEFAULT_FILENAME` and then `print(DEFAULT_FILENAME)`